# Show number of active users of the site

Tags: javascript

I want to show number of active users on this site. Any idea how to get number of active users at this moment.?

Answer (score 0):

This is not default functionality in SharePoint. 
If you need this functionality you will have to create it yourself in Visual Studio.

Easiest will be to create a delegate control that keeps a list of key/value pairs. Key being the username and the value the date and time of the last pageload of that user. Store the list in the Session object.

With every load of your delegate control you log the current user and the datetime in this list.

Using this list of key/value pairs you can display the 'current' amount of users. 'Current' is ofcourse relative. Last 2minutes? Last 24 hours??

Ofcourse you can extend this functionality and make it as complex as your want.

Comment: There seems to be an old SP2007 solution on codeplex http://spcurrentusers.codeplex.com/